# Simplify incrementing option component rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this function that creates a incrementing list of option buttons ranging from 1 to 10 and was wondering if anyone knows how to clean up my existing code. I was hoping that there was a simpler approach that I could take.

```
// create array of length staring from 1 to 10
const years = 10
const terms = Array.from(new Array(years),(val,index)=>index+1);
console.log(terms)
// map option number to tag with label
const properTags = terms.map( (term,index) => {
  return <option value ={term}>
  {term}
  {term === 1 ? "Year" : " Years"}
  </option>
})
```

The expected output a dropdown that has the options ranging 1 Year to 10 Years

Comment: You do not say what years is and since this will be the subject of the function `(var,index) => ` it is very difficult to offer advice.

Comment: years is a number, maybe that wasn't clear

Comment: OK, not sure why you are taking this approach, but terms will be an array with values 1......10. then you have a map of terms with a return value `<option value={term+1}>` which is then followed by some unreachable code ?

Comment: So the returned map will be `<option value="2"><option value="3">......<option value="11">` ? Is this what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: This is what I have, but I feel like it's kinda ugly at the moment. Is there any way to do it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are trying to achieve?

new Array will create an array of the length years, you then need to fill it with something so that you can iterate over it, but really you are just using index to populate the output ?

```js
function makeYears(years) {
  return new Array(years).fill(0).map((year,index) => {
    return '<option value="'+( index+1 ) + ( index == 0 ? "year" : "years" )+'">'
  })
}

console.log(makeYears(10));
```